# google visualization table. Insert an image in a cell (from GDocs)

Tags: google-docs, google-visualization

I'm trying to insert a Google Spreadsheet in an html document and show it as a table.
So, my source is a Google Docs document and I call it with a query

```
(var query = new google.visualization.Query).
```

My table is a list of countries with some data about them. Html visualization until this point is OK.

But I want to add a column with an image (a flag). I don't know if it's possible to do this and, if possible, how to do it.

I've tried to put the link in the cell of the Google Spreadsheet, copy-paste an image, and an img src="...", but no luck. The only thing I have is the code written inside the cell both in the GDocs and the html visualization.

I've defined as an option

```
(var options = {allowHtml: true};
```

Any suggestion?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible, I'm not sure why your options didn't work.

This is an export to csv from my spreadsheet:

```
someContent,someImage
catz,<img src='http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-TzV-DfLU7jc/TagrymLT1HI/AAAAAAAABro/q4Jf1xNjxpk/s1600/ghoul.jpg' />
```

And the relevant javascript code after a call to the spreadsheet:

```
var data = response.getDataTable();
visualization = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('visualization'));
visualization.draw(data, {allowHtml: true});
```

As you noted, `allowHtml: true` is required.